# Suppose $R$ be a ring and $I$ an ideal in R. prove that $rad(I)=R$ if and only if $R=I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal in R. prove that $rad(I)=R$ if and only if $R=I$.

If $R=I$ then $\forall x \in R : x^1 =x \in I$ so $rad(I)=R.$

Can you help me to prove the other side? If it is incorrect please say a counterexample. Thanks.

$$rad(I)= \{ x\in R | \exists n ; x^n\in I \}.$$

Footnote : $R$ has unity.

Comment: Commutative rings or not? With unity, or not necessarily?

Comment: Is it incorrect?

Comment: I'm asking you to clarify your question! Is your ring commutative? Does your ring have an identity? You keep editing, and you keep not answering the query.

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Well, you understand that the definition you give is the definition for **commutative** rings, and that the usual definition for noncommutative rings is that the radical of $I$ is the intersection of all prime ideals that contain $I$, which is usually a *subset* of the set you give?

Comment: Oh Thanks dear! I was not careful :( Now can you complete my proof?

Comment: You have two accounts? That's frowned upon. And I'm not your "dear".

Comment: What? Sorry!!!!

Comment: If you have two accounts, contact the moderators and ask them to merge them.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: To moderators: the two comments originalted from [this account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/581534/amir-hosein-eskandani) and the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115886/discussion-between-jakob-and-arturo-magidin).

Answer (score 4):

This is false in rings without $1$: take any ring $R$ with the zero multiplication. Then $\mathrm{rad}(I)=R$ for all ideals $I$, but any subgroup of the underlying abelian group is an ideal. So any abelian group with proper subgroups and the zero multiplication would be a counterexample.

**Note**: The material below is way too complicated; I somehow got the idea that $\mathrm{rad}(I)$ had been defined as the ideal *generated* by the set of elements $a$ such that $a^n\in I$ for some $n$; the argument below can be used to show that this is in fact *equal* to that set (or equivalently, to show that the set of such elements is an ideal). So, feel free to ignore it.

---

For commutative rings with $1$, let $x\in R$; then there exist $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in\mathrm{rad}(I)$ and elements $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in R$ such that $1=a_1f_1+\cdots+a_nf_n$. The general summand of $(a_1f_1+\cdots+a_nf_n)^N$ looks like
$$\frac{N!}{(i_1!)\cdots(i_n!)}(a_1^{i_1}f_1^{i_1})\cdots(a_n^{i_n}f_n^{i_n}),\qquad\text{where }i_1+\cdots+i_n=N.$$

We know there exists $r_i\gt 0$ such that $f_i^{r_i}\in I$. So pick a sufficiently large $N$ to ensure that each term of $(a_1f_1+\cdots+a_nf_n)^N$ is necessarily in $I$.

Grrr... somehow thought the radical was the ideal generated by the elements whose power lies in $I$, and that it hadn’t been shown it was equal to the elements... this is overly complicated.

Comment: Thanks my friend.

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is a ring with unity and $Rad(I)=R$ then $1 \in Rad(I)$ and hence there exists some $n$ such that $1^n \in I$. This immediatelly implies $I=R$.

Comment: Sigh; somehow I thought “ideal generated by” and that the fact that it is equal to the *set* of such elements was not known...